# Is there any other way to store a java object in a database other than serialization?

Tags: mysql, oracle, hibernate, jdbc, netbeans

In jdbc, storing each and every value in database is time consuming. So i need a method (other than serialization) to store an entire java object (instance of a bean class) to a database, where its values gets stored directly under their respective column names.

Comment: so how would you do a SQL query on a parsed object? (assuming db is not just a place to save your data)

Comment: I am new to this concept and i just wanted to know if there was any other way.

Comment: Perhaps use entity frameworks to work with db objects. which saves time when doing sql operations.

Comment: @krishKM Entity framework is a Microsoft solution for .net.

Comment: Given that you have tagged with _hibernate_ seems to indicate you already know what the solution is to your problem: use an ORM like hibernate.

Answer (score -1):

Without persisting each column yourself, there is no method to store an object in such a manner.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14066293)

Comment: @DimaSan So the (simplified) question is "Is there another method to store an object", with an answer of "No, there is no other method". While not a particularly good answer, there are only so many ways you can write that it is not possible. If you disagree and believe it is possible, feel free to add that as you own answer.